# Use deploy script on Azure release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've created a successful build and release that deployed my React app on a Azure Web App environment. The app I created will be deployed on many different customer environments and I don't want to create each app-service myself so I want to automate that proces. I've exported the template and now I have a `deploy.psh1` file with a `parameters.json` and a `template.json` file. But I'm unsure on what to do now.

I've tried adding a `powershell task` to my release step and paste in the contents of `deploy.sh1` in the inline section but that results in multiple errors:

```
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9475172Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534016Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534117Z Task         : PowerShell
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534203Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Windows, macOS, or Linux.
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534274Z Version      : 2.148.0
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534351Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534429Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)
2019-05-30T19:16:31.9534519Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-30T19:16:32.8910231Z Generating script.
2019-05-30T19:16:32.9442109Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2019-05-30T19:16:32.9667917Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\c37bf4b5-41a1-4125-b7c3-04e0c77fe403.ps1'"
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2330921Z At C:\agent\_work\_temp\c37bf4b5-41a1-4125-b7c3-04e0c77fe403.ps1:30 char:10
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2331159Z +  [string]
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2331234Z +          ~
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2331512Z Missing closing ')' in expression.
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2332867Z At C:\agent\_work\_temp\c37bf4b5-41a1-4125-b7c3-04e0c77fe403.ps1:49 char:1
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2333119Z + )
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2333839Z + ~
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2334117Z Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2335145Z At C:\agent\_work\_temp\c37bf4b5-41a1-4125-b7c3-04e0c77fe403.ps1:29 char:2
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2335362Z +  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2336143Z +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2336345Z Unexpected attribute 'Parameter'.
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2337371Z At C:\agent\_work\_temp\c37bf4b5-41a1-4125-b7c3-04e0c77fe403.ps1:40 char:2
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2337639Z +  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2338286Z +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2338534Z Unexpected attribute 'Parameter'.
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2339929Z     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2340251Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression
2019-05-30T19:16:33.2340819Z  
2019-05-30T19:16:33.3687310Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2019-05-30T19:16:33.3968831Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

So my question is how do I add the creation of the `app-service` during my release?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Resource Group deployment task which you can use directly to deploy ARM templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops

It takes your parameters.json and template.json as input.

Comment: Thanks. I found this https://adatum.no/azure/using-azure-pipelines-to-deploy-arm-templates resource that explains it as well.